# Знаки в мобильной версии профиля

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, дизайн, мобильная-версия

В мобильной версии [профиля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/alexolut?tab=profile&&__=1993413478) отсутствует перевод для редких знаков:

> Rarest badges

А также имеется проблема с вылезанием текста "Серебряный" за границы блока:

[image: серебряный блок]

Возможно имеет смысл добавить множественные формы для золота/серебра/бронзы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил [перевод](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/94464220?key=f23b2cd05eba2b4944fc64a2d3ec3d71) как:

> Самые редкие знаки

Comment: может лучше просто "Редкие знаки"?

Comment: @Denis почему? Дословный перевод и полная версия сайта с Вами не согласны.

Comment: Да, всё верно, невнимательно прочитал)